# Azure Functions: In a Python function under Linux, how do I import a non-standard module such as opencv/imutils?

Tags: python, azure-functions, opencv

I am trying to export my computer vision API, which is functioning correctly under macOS, to an Azure Function.

I tried to use the docker approach:

```
func azure functionapp publish --build-native-deps
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
can't import cv2 and imutils
```

[log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rql9c.jpg)

and

```
Exception: ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here is the requirements.txt:

[requirements.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZfwH.png)

How do I solve this problem? Or must I switch to AWS Lambda?

I have access to Kudu if that's helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sometimes you have to compile cv2 to work in your local linux setup (that was the case for OpenCV v3.2.* on RaspberryPi in two years ago. I do not know, if that is the solution in your case. If I recall correctly, that required of compiling imutils, too. Reserve half to one workday for it (if you are doing this first time).

Comment: A really good, timely question! Why was this downvoted? Perhaps it should be more focussed on Azure functions label-wise?

Comment: @OP Please insert your logs and requirements.txt as ASCII rather than images - the latter are much less friendly

Answer (score 1):

The Azure team has updated the default function image to include libglib2.0-dev

You will need to install the headless version of OpenCV through pip instead of the default.

https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python-headless/

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is lack of the necessary library `libgthread`. To fix it, you need to add it into your Docker file to build your own image for your function deployment.

On Azure, please follow the section [`Build the image from the Docker file`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image#build-the-image-from-the-docker-file) of the offical document `Create a function on Linux using a custom image` to add the code below in [`azure-functions/python:2.0`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker/blob/master/host/2.0/stretch/amd64/python.Dockerfile) Docker file.

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libglib2.0-dev
```

But it will add a new docker image layer, so you can add `libglib2.0-dev` into [`azure-functions/base:2.0`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker/blob/master/host/2.0/stretch/amd64/base.Dockerfile) like below.

```
# Line 19
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg wget unzip libglib2.0-dev && \
    wget https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/ExtensionBundles/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/1.0.0/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.1.0.0.zip && \
    mkdir -p /FuncExtensionBundles/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/1.0.0 && \
    unzip /Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.1.0.0.zip -d /FuncExtensionBundles/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/1.0.0 && \
    rm -f /Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.1.0.0.zip
```

Comment: Thanks man. Currently I moved my service to AWS lambda since it is more 'python friendly' and not 'preview version' for python, and it works perfectly. But I will definitely try it this weekends. This is exactly what I want to do using the bespoke docker method.

Comment: Is this the _only_ way to get "non-standard" python modules into an Azure Function? Once the packages are baked into the Docker image, can I still get the benefit of "lite" function publishing on top of that image, or must I do a Docker build every time locally as part of publication?