# Error while importing python cv2 in Azure function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, opencv

We are deploying python based Azure Function using Azure CLI but getting this below error while importing cv2 library.

ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

We are not using any docker image. Would prefer a non-docker based solution.

```
Exception: ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Stack:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 239, in _handle__function_load_request
    func_request.metadata.entry_point)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 66, in load_function
    mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/FaceFinderHttpTrigger/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
```

Comment: You could try to pitch the installation of `libglib2.0-0` into the Azure Functions sandbox - [this repo](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions) would be a good start. Else, build your own container image and have no dependency on the system libs underneath. See if you can maybe use Pillow instead if you're only doing some image manipulation. Pillow works just fine right on the sandbox - see an example here - https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/tree/master/v2functions/blob-trigger-watermark-blob-out-binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar SO thread [Azure Functions: In a Python function under Linux, how do I import a non-standard module such as opencv/imutils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56015616/azure-functions-in-a-python-function-under-linux-how-do-i-import-a-non-standar/56053505#56053505) with the same issue as yours.

Due to the `libgthread` shared library is a Linux base library, per my experience, it seems to be caused by Azure CLI could not package these Python packages with native dependencies as Azure Function. So the only solution I think is to build your Azure Function as a Docker container by yourself as the offical document [`Create a function on Linux using a custom image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image#build-the-image-from-the-docker-file) said, or try to use Azure CLI command `func azure functionapp publish` with `--build-native-deps` option to automatically build and configure the dependencies using a Docker container.

Also as I known, there is a blog [`OPENCV WITH AZURE FUNCTIONS`](https://armiev.com/opencv-with-azure-functions/) which seems to work fine with opencv for Azure Functions, but it just run on local development environment, not on cloud, as my view. So I still recommend you to deploy your app as a Docker contaier for the app using native dependencies.